Second JWT authentication with policy not getting to the controller method
I am trying to add a second JWT authentication. It seems that everything works, until it is trying to access the method in the controller.
At first I define the name of the scheme:
const string bearerJwtWrite = "JwtWrite";

and add the JWT bearer
builder.Services
       .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
           { ... }
       .AddJwtBearer(bearerJwtWrite, options => 
           {
               options.Authority = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Write:Issuer"];
               options.Audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Write:Audience"];
               // options.Challenge = bearerJwtWrite;
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters

it also gets to the validated token part when doing a web request
    OnTokenValidated = context =>
    {
            // Add custom claims to the principal if the token is valid
            var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(
                        ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                        context.Scheme.Name,
                        ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Claim_AdminPrivilege_API_jwt_Write")
                };

            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
            
            return Task.CompletedTask;
    },

after that, it enters the constructor of the API controller and that's all. It is not going further, only when I remove Authorize from the controller.
The policy is defined like this:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("Role_AdminPrivilege_API_jwt_Write", p => {
        // Add the authentication scheme for certificate
        p.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(bearerJwtWrite);
        //p.RequireAssertion(context => true);
        p.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Claim_AdminPrivilege_API_jwt_Write");
    });
     
});

And my method is:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "JwtWrite")]
[Authorize(Policy = "Role_AdminPrivilege_API_jwt_Write")]
[HttpPost("CreateEndpointAdminJwt")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEndpointAdminJwt([FromBody]MyModel model)

Another function that uses JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme works fine.
Edit:
sorry, everyone. The error was that I was not sharing all my code. The problem was that in OnMessageReceived I read the reader to the end, but did not reset the position:
var jsonBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;

After that the body was passed in the correct way

Does your application respond "403 Forbidden" or with something else?

Hi @M.Elghamry, you are right. The error was too logically. It was 400 - "The input does not contain any JSON tokens". The problem was, I did not reset the position after reading the Body, and when I did not use authorization, it of course it did not enter the JWT validation.
